# Could not find the GDAL library in django. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Tags: django, gdal

I am working in django project and need to use `PointField` imported from `django.contrib.gis.db.models`.

To use it, I installed GDAL by `brew install gdal`.

When I enter `gdal-config --version` in terminal after installing it, I got the message `3.3.1`.

I believe this tells GDAL has been successfully installed.

I also updated the database setting in `settings.py` like this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql",
        'NAME': config("DB_PROD_NAME"),
        'USER': config("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT")
        },
    }
```

And this is the `models.py` where `PointField` is used.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Address(models.Model):
    address_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_name_detail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_type = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    address_coord = models.PointField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'address'
```

The problem is when I try `python3 manage.py runserver` or import the model Address in `views.py`,

I get an error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.2.0", "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.`

By adding

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = config('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = config('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

in `settings.py`, there is no longer error when I enter `python3 manage.py runserver`, but it is not the case in importing Address model.

What can I do for this?

I am using M1 Mackbook Air. Can it be a problem?

Comment: I suggest downgrading your gdal version. I tried version 2.4.4 and it worked, while version 3 did not. I also find that installing gdal into a conda environment is less prone to problems. All of the binaries are included.

Comment: @RobertDavy so the solution is `brew install gdal==2.4.4` or `gdal@2.4.4`? right?

Comment: @alial-karaawi no comment - I almost always install gdal into conda environments. I believe this eliminates most gdal install problems that people encounter. [See here for miniconda install instructions](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

Comment: @RobertDavy Now, I installed gdal with conda I activate the `base` environment when gdal is installed and inside it I activated my pipenv environment then I ran my app and it is still shows `can't find gdal`, How to get gdal path where the package is installed?

Comment: full error message `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.`

Comment: Try this: `conda install -c conda-forge django gdal<3.0 python<3.9`